# Context Expression Extension Setup

Tags: cme, 2013

As of **SDL Tridion 2013 SP1**, we can integrate **SDL Intelligent Marketing Suite** (CMA) with SDL Tridion's Content Manager Explorer through **Target Groups**.

Two high-level questions on this integration:

- How do we set it up? Is there an installer or is this just out-of-the-box with 2013 SP1?
- Do we need to do anything for the Target Groups? Are they set up with the install or does CMA add new ones as needed?

**Edit**: I moved question on the tag to "[Tag for SDL Intelligent Marketing Suite (CMA)?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/253/46)"

Comment: Is there anything in the installation manual for 2013 SP1 covering the setup? Also, you should probably post your tag related question to meta.

Comment: +1 to moving the tag question to meta, CMA (and other SDL products) may not have a place here - other than the scope of Tridion integration

Comment: The docs describe the integration, but I couldn't find the details. Product management explained (and answered below) the integration comes "for free" as part of the install or upgrade. I'll put the CMA question on meta, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Context Expression Extension is installed as part of the standard Tridion CM installer (optional).

You will need to use CMA to populate these Target Groups - though they are stored and exposed in Tridion as the good old Target Groups, you'll soon realize they are not your father's Target Groups:

- These Target Groups can be published
- Target Group definitions (i.e., the expressions) are stored separately from the pages (and therefore can be updated without republishing all pages)

CMA will add/update/delete Target Groups as needed, and this is all controlled from CMA itself. There is also a CD-side extension that 1) uses the Context Engine to evaluate these expressions and 2) provides storage capability for ADF variables (to be used in CMA).