# Relationship between CMA Segment and Target Group

Tags: cme

Related to [Context Expression Extension Setup](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3762/46), Campaign Manager has an [profile export tool](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Campaign%20Manager%2050%20online%20help-v1/GUID-62E251F3-29A5-4D2D-B879-9959704CDFA0), which integrates with SDL Tridion in this way.

> The Profile Rule Export tool allows users to export the syntax or
>   definition of the segment document in Campaign Manager based on Web
>   Data analytics, to a text format, for transfer to the Target Groups
>   component of Tridion.

Using the export tool, are the segment rules directly translated in the same rules in the Target Group?

For example, if a hypothetical segment includes users where `age > 21` and `income = high`, does the Target Group store these rules as well?

*Also, to do something like this, is Audience Manager required?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (I never did it hands on so can't say for sure), Audience Manager is *not* required to export CMA segments as JEXL content expressions to be stored in Target Groups in Tridion.

The integration between CMA and Tridion uses the Core Service to update the Target Groups, which are then published to the website and can be evaluated using the ADF.

Of course, if the parameters that build up the JEXL Content expression happen to be Audience Manager profile field values, then yes - you will need Audience Manager and its corresponding ADF cartridge, to provide these values to evaluate the expressions.